# Opening a .mp4 file with notepad++

Tags: video

I am just a curious person and one day i was watching a video on my laptop and when I right clicked on it, a window popped up and out of several options one was edit with notepad++, out of curiosity I opened the video but all i saw was jibberish. I think it is some kind of encryption or coding of the video but actually I don't have any idea. Can anyone please help me or atleast direct me what to search to know more about this code

Is there any way to meaningfully edit the code? I have a video which i can't skip forward, otherwise it runs good, E.g. if I am watching it at 2:00 and want to skip ahead at 5:00, it just continues from 2:00 but after 3 minutes it will reach 5:00, I searched on a lot of sites and people said your video is corrupted or there is something wrong with the coding of video, can I do something to reverse corrupt this? Is reverse corrupt even a thing?

Comment: What were you _expecting_ to see? A transcript of the video?

Comment: Notepad++ is a text editor. For non text files, such as video files, what you are seeing is to be expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any file on the drive is just a series of 0 and 1.  Some groups of them in some locations have special meaning (like the "magic bytes" that would indicate that "this is a mp4 file", etc)

When you open the mp4 file with notepad++, notepad++ ignored the "magic bytes" that say "hey this is a mp4 file!" because it simply doesn't know any better and instead assumed the file was just a badly written text file and read it into memory as such, and assumed the 0 and 1 were plain ASCII text characters and displayed the result to you.

There are all sorts of non-printable characters when something like that happens, and some include calls to the PC speaker system (system beep), etc. so you can get really weird results if you simply `cat` the file too... although some files on some systems - a simple WAV file on a Linux system for example - can be made sense of by sending it directly to the sound hardware `cat /path/to/foo.wav > /dev/dsp`